Flutter splash screen still white
I'm facing issues with the splash screen in Flutter.
I'm using the flutter_native_splash package to change it, but it still shows a blank screen without the icon and color configured in the yaml file. When I run it on the Pixel emulator, I can see the white background and the small icon, but on my physical Xiaomi device, I don't see anything, just white.
This is my yaml splash config:
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#001c31"
  color_dark: "#001c31"
  android: true
  ios: true
  background_image: "assets/icon/app-icon.png"

This is the launch_background.xml (is the same in the drawable-night and the v21):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>

I noticed that before setting it up i could also see the blank screen instead of the default icon with the F for flutter
I tried flutter clean, doing it without the flutter_native_splash but I end up with the same result.
